# Bond attributes with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I last used chemfig a while ago. Much has changed since then, especially the `\charge` command.

I'm trying to draw a simple molecule. In number 3 it looks exactly as I want, but I'd like to be able to be able to have the methyl first in the code. I do this in #2 (works well) and #4 (adding `\charge` causes an error. Why is this? How can I avoid it?

```
! Package chemfig Error: no atom found at position 2, pershaps you mispelled the optional argument of the bond...\CF_error ...e {Package \CFname \space Error: #1.} -[:-30]F}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz,margin=1.5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

% works with methyl as branch
\chemfig{H_2N(-[:90,,2])
-[:-30]F}

% correct, but without charge
\chemfig{-[:270,,,2]H_2N
-[:-30]F}

% #1 with charge
\chemfig{H_2\charge{45:2pt=$+$}{N}(-[:90,,2])
-[:-30]F}

% #2 with charge
\chemfig{-[:270,,,2]H_2\charge{45:2pt=$+$}{N}
-[:-30]F}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the `H_2` and the `N` with `|` and then you can tell `chemfig` where to arrive at the atom.
Is this how you want it?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{-[:-90,,,2]H_2|\charge{45:2pt=$+$}{N}-[:-30]F}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is! Does `\charge` fuse the `H_2` and the `N` somehow?

Comment: @imp54 I can only guess how it works:

You draw a molecule like `CH3-CH3`. `\chemfig` splits these groups (CH3) into their atoms (ignoring that `H3` is not a real atom). So `CH3` is split into `C` and `H3`. But `\chemfig` ignores everything in `{}` according to the `\chemfig` manual. Therefore the `N` in brackets of `\charge` is not recognized as an atom and thus it is not available as a destination for a bond. That is way your error says that there is no atom at this position. Splitting these molecules manualy tells `\chemfig` here is a molecule that consists of more than one atom.